# Nexus OOS - Clean up the proxy/attributes/

Tags: proxy, administration, nexus, sonatype

I got a Nexus OOS instance with the following settings:

- proxy of the http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
- I override the "local storage location" with a path to a network device

Everything is ok and my Nexus instance works fine... but I notice the number of inodes grows a lot.
After a little check, I can tell every inodes come from the *proxy/attributes/* directory.
According to the documentation:

> Stores data about the files contained in a remote repository. Each
>   proxy repository has a subdirectory in the proxy/attributes/ directory
>   and every file that Nexus has interacted with in the remote repository
>   has an XML file which captures such data as the: last requested
>   timestamp, the remote URL for a particular file, the length of the
>   file, and the digests for a particular file among other things. If you
>   need to backup the local cached contents of a proxy repository, you
>   should also back up the contents of the proxy repository's directory
>   under proxy/attributes/.

Ok I understand why there is a lot of little files in this location but I have a dummy question: to avoid to reach my inode limit, could I periodically clean up the content of *proxy/attributes/*, without breaking anything and does these files will be recreated 'on demand' if needed?

I find nothing about it...

Any clue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details on the contents of the working folder here: https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+Workspace+Directories+Analysis

The part you're specifically interested in is this:

> /Proxy: This folder contains an "attributes" subfolder, that holds as
>   many subfolders as many repos you have (repoId is the name of
>   these). This is the place where "item attributes" are persisted as lots
>   of very small files. These files contain information about expiration
>   status and are consulted during proxying. Therefore, they have impact
>   on proxy and group lookup speed if stored on a slow disk. These files
>   are recreated on demand if they are missing or corrupted and thus
>   don't need to be backed up.

Hope that helps, if you need more realtime assistance, feel free top hop onto the user list or irc: http://nexus.sonatype.org/project-information.html